# C# & Unity - Adding and manipulating List elements with multiple values

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

Unity & C# (and generally new to coding) beginner here, so there is probably easy solution for this or i'm doing something terribly wrong. Also apologies for lack of terminology knowledge.

I'm trying to add element to List with specific values, but i can't quite find the correct syntax to successfully add it.

Here is a code:

```
public List<ActiveEffects> activeEffects;

public void AddEffectToEnemy(Effect effect, int duration){
    activeEffects.Add(effect, duration);
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ActiveEffects{
    public Effect effect;
    public int duration;
}
```

What i want to do, is when AddEffectToEnemy function is executed, new element will be added with both variables (effect and duration) assigned. This is probably not the correct way, as the error i'm getting is "No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments".

What i'm trying to do with this is a create a temporary 'storage' of applied effects to enemy in RPG-like game. At certain point AddEffectToEnemy is executed, which should apply specific effect to enemy for (duration) amount of time, by adding element with that information to activeEffects List. (other part of script will be checking regularly for active effects in this List)

Can you please point me in right direction on how to properly implement this? I feel like i'm not doing this the right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: activeEffects.Add(new ActiveEffects(effect, duration)); you want to add a new instance of the type into the list.

Comment: also just FYI you really don't need "[System.Serializable]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how Object-Oriented Programming works. Here's a quick explanation:

```
public class YourClass {
    //Fields, properties, methods, etc go here
}
```

Will *define* a `class`, which is kind of a blueprint of *what* an object *represents*.

```
public YourClass someName;
```

Will *define* a `field`, which is kind of a *reference* to a *characteristic* that an object *contains* (in case of private, protected, etc fields, it includes what it must contain for it's inner workings).

---

However, a *definition* by itself does nothing. It's like *saying* "a chair is an object with four legs and a flat top to sit upon" without actually *having* such object to sit upon.

In OOP, the equivalent of the "physical" chair is an ***instance***. That's the stuff that is created when you see `new YourClass(/*parameters may or may not be here*/)`.

---

With that general concept explained, let's switch to understanding your mistake specifically:

```
public List<ActiveEffects> activeEffects;
```

This defines a ***field*** of a `List` of type `ActiveEffects`; meaning that it does nothing as-is, and expects to reference/contain an ***instance*** of a `List` object, that itself will expect ***instances*** of `ActiveEffects`.

For that list to be useful, you need to initialize/instantiate it:

```
public List<ActiveEffects> activeEffects = new List<ActiveEffects>();
```

Sometimes you need some processing done as part of your classes' instances' creations, and that is where `Constructors` come in. Your `ActiveEffects` class is kind of a weak example of this. It doesn't require any real processing, but it's better to have a constructor for convenience of adding instances of it to lists.

Without constructors:

```
var activeEffectToAdd = new ActiveEffects(); //A variable is like a temporary field
//We use a variable here to hold & reference the instance of ActiveEffects while we modify it
activeEffectToAdd.effect = someEffectReference; //Assign the effect
activeEffectToAdd.duration = someEffectDuration; //Assign the duration
activeEffects.Add(activeEffectToAdd); //We add that same reference [& instance] to the list after it's modified
```

A constructor, in this case, allows us to move the assignment inside the definition of the class, and thus assign the `effect` and `duration` during the instantiation through the use of `parameters`:

```
public class ActiveEffects{
    public Effect effect;
    public int duration;

    public ActiveEffects(Effect effect, int duration){
        this.effect = effect; //[this.] removes the ambiguity and allows us to use the same name for the parameter as we have for the field
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}
```

Now that you have a working constructor, you can initialize `effect` and `duration` straight from the `ActiveEffects` instance's creation:

```
new ActiveEffects(someEffect, someDuration);
```

Now that you actually have a working list, and simple `ActiveEffects` instantiation, we can populate that list with instances of effects:

```
activeEffects.Add(new ActiveEffects(someEffect, 1));
activeEffects.Add(new ActiveEffects(someOtherEffect, 3));
activeEffects.Add(new ActiveEffects(someOtherOtherEffect, 5));
```

---

Extra recommendations:
Your naming scheme is confusing and is going to give you problems soon enough.

Remember that classes are ***definitions***, and so your `ActiveEffects` class is misnamed, in that each instance of it represents only ***one*** active effect. Name if `ActiveEffect` (no plural) instead!

Your list's name is also probably too close to the name of the class, so to avoid confusion, name it `activeEffectsList`.

Remove your `AddEffectToEnemy()` method entirely. Your list is public, and the method is not needed at this time. Something similar *might* be needed when you want to *encapsulate* your list, but that is still a bit off your skill level and you shouldn't worry about it for now.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, i'm wrapping my head around this, with your suggestions i'm able to now add effects! One more question, is there a way i can now access values? For example if i want to change duration in one of the instances and eventually destroy the instance once duration == 0. Thanks